# Energy Levels in Double Finite Well potentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

Why is there a behaviour where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are close to each other? This question is already answered [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373585/) but I did not understand the explanation about symmetric and asymmetric terms as I do not know about the mathematics of it. Is there a more simple explanation to it?

Comment: What behavior are you asking about, specifically?

Comment: The behaviour where the energy levels $E_1$ and $E_2$ are close to each other. Similarly it occurs in $E_3$ and $E_4$ as well.

Comment: It might be helpful to define what you mean by $E_1$, $E_2$, etc. instead of having users dig through other posts to find the notation.